# Do i need to install all sdk android tools

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

i just recently installed my new sdk manager to install the android platforms but my internet is little bit slow. and i want someone to tell me how much things i need to install from it 

 Image:  
https://s26.postimg.org/mp8sidp5l/littlebit.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Just install the basic tools recommended by Android Studio and then install what is required afterwards. Studio will prompt if you do not have the required platform required.

Comment: hello. thanks for your reply i use eclipse not ANDROID STUDIO